# Indeterminate number of arguments c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a variable number of arguments here.

```
Codification codebook = new codification(data,"Attr1","Attr2",..."AttrnumOfAttrColumns,"Result")
```

and also here:

```
int[][] inputs = symbols.ToJagged<int>("Attr1","Arrt2",..."AttrnumOfAttrColumns);
```

I was trying to do it with a for loop which is not the right.Is there a way to do this?

```
Codification codebook = new Codification(data, for (int i = 0; i < numOfAttrColumns; i++) {return "Attr"+Convert.ToString(i) }, "Result");
```

Comment: Codification codebook = new codification(data,new string[] {"Attr1","Attr2",..."AttrnumOfAttrColumns,"Result"});

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP's 3rd code block is what they're trying to get help with, granted it was a bit confusing.

Comment: OP I think what you were after is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rsqdpz)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Accord.net manual](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Filters_Codification.htm)

You can put

```
Codification codebook = new codification(data, new string[] {
  "Attr1", "Attr2", ..., "AttrnumOfAttrColumns", "Result"});
```